# Simplyscroll content id not showing the iframe content

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

i applied simply scroll jquery plugin to ul tab for scrolling purpose. the scrolling is working fine . But the scroll bar content not showing the iframe tag . the html code as follow:

```
<ul id="scroller">
  <p> some text </p>
 <iframe id="myyoutube" width="210px"  height="200px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tRrHM16jjog" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
 </ul>
```

could any one please suggest to visible the iframe tag in scrollbar content id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({});
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="scroller">
  <ul>  
    <li><p> some text </p></li>
    <li><iframe id="myyoutube" width="210px"  height="200px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tRrHM16jjog" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine for me

Comment: try to inserti into a div called"scroller" instead of the id into the ul because my code works fine